# In WinRT can the EasClientDeviceInformation.Id be used as a unique identifer for a specific user on a specific device?

Tags: windows, windows-runtime

In our WinRT application, we need a unique identifier for a logged in user that 100% consistent between app launches on the same device and *persists* between app uninstallations and re-installations on the same device.  The identifier only has to be consistent for the same logged in user.

We have looked into the [ASHWID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj553431.aspx) but "hardware drift" will permute this ID in unpredictable ways and it is not suitable for our design.

Question: Could the [EasClientDeviceInformation.Id](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.exchangeactivesyncprovisioning.easclientdeviceinformation.id.aspx) be suitable? It sounds good but I can't find much documentation or use cases for it. When and how might this ID change?

> ***EasClientDeviceInformation.Id | id property***
>
> Returns the identifier of the local computer. The Id property
>   represents the DeviceId using the GUID truncated from the first 16
>   bytes of the SHA256 hash of MachineID, User SID, and App ID where the
>   MachineID uses the SID of the local users group. Each component of the
>   GUID is returned in network byte order.

Comment: Hi, did you get any success with this. I am also evaluating this for my app.

Comment: You can use `SystemIdentification.GetSystemIdForUser()`.